# Ven. Ajahn Chah's Teachings on Meditation practice as a westerner

Tags: monk, ordination, thai

For a long time I have wanted to ordain and I might be able to do it in 2-3 years from now. I read that as a westerner one can ordain in the Ven. Ajahn Chah tradition in Thailand. He went to great extends to create a monastery where especially westerners, non-thai speakers could ordain and learn the Dhamma.

My question is what kind of Meditation practice is being taught?

Answer (score 1):

It appears that some teachers and traditions are more focused on *samatha* and *jhana* like Pa Auk Sayadaw, Ajahn Chah and Ajahn Chah's disciple, Ajahn Brahm.

And then there are other teachers and traditions that are more focused on *vipassana* like Mahasi Sayadaw, Ledi Sayadaw, Sayagyi U Ba Khin and his student S.N. Goenka, Ajahn Tong Sirimangalo and his disciple, Ajahn Yuttadhammo.

Samatha is cultivation of serenity, and vipassana is cultivation of insight.

Ultimately both are needed.

From a Dhamma talk by [Ajahn Chah](http://www.ajahnchah.org/book/About_Ajahn_Chah.php) entitled "[Unshakeable Peace](http://www.ajahnchah.org/book/Unshakeable_Peace1_2.php)":

> Meditation is like a single stick of wood. Insight (*vipassanā*) is one
> end of the stick and serenity (*samatha*) the other. If we pick it up,
> does only one end come up or do both? When anyone picks up a stick
> both ends rise together. Which part then is *vipassanā*, and which is
> *samatha*? Where does one end and the other begin? They are both the
> mind.

Comment: Thank you so much for this! Really appreciate it.